# Export annotations from (non Amazon) book on kindle

Tags: kindle, calibre, annotations

I imported a manuscript (not published by Amazon, or anyone else, at least yet) into my Kindle and used the annotation feature to note down corrections to be made.

I would now like to send the corrections back to the author but I can't find a way to export the annotations with the context or with a meaningful reference to which paragraph they refer to.

The "My Clippings.txt" file looks like this:

```
Book title 13-03-2019 (xxx@gmail.com)
-  La tua evidenziazione alla posizione 3533-3533 | Aggiunto in data lunedì 1 aprile 2019 20:10:52

ranger
```

the only clue to what the note refers too is "3533-3533", which is not very useful.

I have tried the Annotations Calibre plugin (ver 1.9.2), but the output only indicates the note position as a number (see image).

[image: Annotations plugin output]

Is there an alternative way to get the annotations together with the text? Is there any way to turn these numbers into the originally highlighted text (possibly with some context)?